# jQuery Toggle Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, fade

What I'm trying to accomplish seems quite simple however, I'm not great at jQuery.

I did try to get as close as possible to a solution but whenever I click on the anchor tag twice, everything disappears. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I would like .`slider1` to be visible by default and .`slider2` to be hidden.
Also, when the anchor `"Fader"` is clicked, .`slider1` is hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/GQJxv/

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed up the code for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZAPwD/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(".slider1").fadeIn("fast");
$("a.slider").click(function() {
$(".slider2").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $(".slider1").fadeIn("fast");
});
});

$("a.fader").click(function() {
$(".slider1").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $(".slider2").fadeIn("fast");
});
});
```

This looks like it cross fades pretty nicely:
http://martin-fleming.co.uk/examples/jquery-crossfade/

Comment: That's also a great solution. Thank You!